# Reset PrimeFaces DataTable state (filter, sorting, paging)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'd like to reset the filter, sort and paging state of an PrimeFaces DataTable. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do so. Especially reseting the sort state is difficult.

What I did until now is:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(componentId);
if (dataTable != null) {
    dataTable.setSortOrder("ascending");  // reset sortOrder
    dataTable.setFirst(0);                // reset page
    dataTable.setFilteredValue(null);     // reset filter
    dataTable.setFilters(null);
}
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, hidden in this sample http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml on tab `ColumnsView.java`:

```
table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
```

Comment: I can confirm that with Primefaces 5.3 dataTable.setValueExpression("sortBy", null) and dataTable.setSortBy(null); together resulted in a DataTable that has no sorting indicatedin the column headers.

Comment: @alfonx any idea how is this on PrimeFaces 7.0?

Answer (score 3):

```
dataTable.setSortBy(null);
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0

Comment: I can confirm that with Primefaces 5.3 dataTable.setValueExpression("sortBy", null) and dataTable.setSortBy(null); together resulted in a DataTable that has no sorting indicatedin the column headers. – alfonx just now   edit

Answer (score 3):

Inside the LazyDataModel load I call the method with this code:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:dataTableItem");
dataTable.setFirst(0);
dataTable.reset();
dataTable.setSortBy(null);
```

Comment: This is a good solution and more complete solution especially for cases when the datatable is not binded on backend.

Answer (score 0):

First I reset the sort state as in the other answers:

```
dataTable.setSortBy(null);
```

However, this didn't reset the displayed codes in the table for me. It was still displaying the previously filtered results since I had set the `filteredValue` attribute on my datatable to a field in a view scoped bean. I fixed that problem by setting my `filteredValue` field to the `value` field, setting the current filtered results to the complete data set.

Answer (score -2):

```
private DataTable filtervalue;
getter and setter of filtervalue ..........
call resetValue(); method on datatable
as  filtervalue.resetValue();
```

Hope it works

Comment: How is this anwer an improvement compared to what is already in the question (which is about sorting).... And please post 'real' code..